# In what order should I read the bonus materials for Torment: Tides of Numenera?

Tags: torment-tides-of-numenera

There are several stories that supplement Torment: Tides of Numenera, and are included in deluxe or Kickstarter versions:

- "*The Red Hand*" by Nathan Long (From the Depths: Red).
- "*The Four Lessons of the Great Chila*" by Mur Lafferty (From the Depths: Silver).
- "*The Last Days of Archopalasia*" by Tony Evans (From the Depths: Blue).
- "*Gate to the Abyss*" by Adam Heine (From the Depths: Gold).
- "*For the Common Good*" by Ray Vallese (From the Depths: Indigo).
- "*Palimpsest*" by Monte Cook.
- "*The Last of the Tabaht*" by Colin McComb.
- "*So Long as You Can See the Moon*" comic by Patrick Rothfuss and Nate Taylor.

I want to know in what order should I read these stories, and play the main game, for maximum enjoyment.

That is likely to be very subjective, but I think it breaks down into a few objective questions.  In decreasing order of importance:

- Do any of the stories (or game) spoil a plot twist in any of the others?
- Do any of the stories (or game) assume that the reader already understands concepts or information from one of the others?
- What is the chronological order of the stories (and game)?